# Install wire rope to several steel tubes?

Tags: roof, exterior, patio, wire, steel

We have 13 1.5" round steel tubes that go around a small area in our backyard Each tube has a small hole that crosses the tube. I'm including the basic design:

[image]

I would like to use wire rope (or steel cable) to go around all these tubes, and make a rudimentary fence.

What would I need? The tubes are galvanized, but I wouldn't want water to go inside the tube.

Thanks.

These are the regular tubes:
[image]

This is the regular wire:
[image]

Comment: How strong does the fence need to be?

Comment: The tubes are solid since they're inside concrete. The fence should be strong.

Comment: Strong enough to withstand a light breeze?  Strong enough to keep in a dog?  Strong enough to keep a hungry bear out while a litter of piglets squeals inside?  Please at least minimally quantify "strong".

Comment: Strong enough to withstand a breeze. What difference would that make in explaining how to install the cable?

Comment: if you put much tension on the cable it will tend to pull the supports inward.

Comment: You say the pipes already have a hole in them.  What details are you looking for other than "Run the cable through the holes in the pipes and put a metal cap on each pipe to keep put water"?

Comment: Is it really as simple as running the cable through the holes and putting a metal cap?

Comment: The wire would eventually connect to each other. How would that be done?

Comment: @rbhat Look for videos on "How to Attach Wire Rope to Turnbuckles".

Comment: The turnbuckles were exactly what I was looking for. I just didn't know how they were called. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The chain link fence folks have all kinds of fence post caps that could be used to keep the rain out. Also there are nylon caps for EMT.  You could convert the tubing to iron pipe threads and install threaded PVC caps.  As to the holes and lacing the cable, before installing poles, I would put them on the drill press and pre-drill.

Comment: You can also use some outdoor rated silicon caulk to help plug the holes the wires go through, after the wire are installed.

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods of attaching cables together in the manner that you are pursuing.

One option attach two ends of cables via a screw type connector:

[image: Screw Cable Connector]

Another option requires a crimping tool where the coupler is compressed around the cable ends.

[image: crimping cable connectors]

More information about other methods of connecting cables to posts can be found when researching "Cable Rail Systems".

A simple fence post cap and a little bit of silicone caulking would keep the water out of the post. These are fairly cheap at your local home improvement or fencing supply company.

[image: Fence Post Cap]