# Clips for holes where wire rope goes through?

Tags: roof, fence

For simplicity's sake, let's say I'm building a small square fence like the one below. It has four 2" pipes that are secured to the concrete. The wire rope will go through each tube, like in the picture. The wire has to be tight enough so that the wire is straight, but that's it.

Few questions:

- What clips (if any) should I put in each hole to secure the wire? If clips are needed, would the holes need to be a certain size? These clips would also prevent water from going in. How are these clips called?[image]
- How do I tie the two loose ends of the wire rope to each other?

Thanks.

Comment: related https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/128896/71370

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for grommets, specifically rubber grommets would seal the holes.

As to connecting the ends, whenever I've seen this type of system the ends aren't connected.  Each end would have a type of swage terminating the wire rope and be secured to a bolt or turnbuckle to allow the rope to be tightened.

Comment: If you cap the tops of you posts, the rain water entering the pipes will be inconsequential.  You could also make loops out of the ends of your cable and couple the ends together with coil springs.